# "Oxygen rich environment that scales love so much?"

Tags: headlinese

I can not understand the meaning of this part of sentence.
Below is original.
[image]

Comment: What context did this image appear in?  I am not 100% sure what "scales" refers to, but it is probably obvious in context.

Comment: Is this a picture of a furnace or kiln or something like that? I think the caption is anthropomorphizing the "scales" a little bit, and talking about them as if they were animals who love oxygen. A less metaphorical way of saying it would be "oxygen-rich environment that causes the formation of scale." (Usually it is "scale", an uncountable noun, referring to the substance, not "scales", which would refer to pieces of scale.)

Comment: Look up **[Mill scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill_scale)** at Wikipedia. This oxide forms in the presence of oxygen, so depriving an environment of oxygen will decrease the likelihood of its formation.

Answer (score 3):

This ***scales*** refers to [***oxidation scale***: thin flakes of oxidized metal, caused by heat.](https://books.google.com/books?id=aHd4-4lIa8oC&pg=PA239)

According to Collins English Dictionary (via The Free Dictionary), **scale** is:

> ​7. (Metallurgy) a flaky black oxide of iron formed on the surface of iron or steel at high temperatures
>   8. (Metallurgy) any oxide formed on a metal during heat treatment

Because the forming of such an oxide requires lots of oxygen, the blacksmith does their work in "the oxygen rich environment" which "scales love so much". Typically, *scale* would be used uncountably. I guess that they said *scales* because the speaker is a blacksmith so they may have their own way of talking, or maybe it's anthropomorphizing like Wim Lewis said in [his comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75846/oxygen-rich-environment-that-scales-love-so-much/75858#comment146103_75846) above.

Comment: Also note that the oxide (that "scale" refers to) is usually black, hence the word "blacksmith".